# Setting Bash variable with osascript always incorrect.

Tags: bash, osx, variable

I'm trying to set a variable based on user input.  I know that what I have configured to prompt the user will either respond with "button returned:yes" or "button returned:no".

I would like the variable to be set to "True" if the button returns yes.  and "False" if the button returns no.

This is what I have so far:

```
response="button returned:yes"
var=`/usr/bin/osascript -e 'display dialog "Is a reboot required?" buttons {No,Yes}'`
/bin/test "$response" = "$var" && reboot="True" || reboot="False"
```

What am I doing wrong?  The $reboot variable is always setting to false, regardless of the user input. This is a bash script, intended to be run on a macOS system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line to the end of a copy of your script:

```
echo "r: '$response'; v: '$var'; b: '$reboot'"
```

gives this output:

```
r: 'button returned:yes'; v: 'button returned:yes '; b: 'False'
```

It seems that `osascript` is appending a space to the output, and since `"string"` is not equal to `"string "`, your test fails to act as you expect.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  I simply set $response to include a space at the end.